# Babel (@babel/types) JSDoc ast, where are the typings?

Tags: babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, jsdoc

Looking at AST explorer, JSDoc comments are parsed into a nice domain specific AST. Example:

https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/72b1e9eb9b8e91a5bcf0af8eb281788c/c6944194a73654cf234ad79a004558ca8e67e286

So the following code:

```
/**
 * @mytag Test comment
 */
const X = 1
```

Looks something like this parsed:

```
VariableStatement
|- declarationList... (irrelevant)
|- jsDoc
   |- JSDocComment
      |- tags
         |-JSDocCommentTag
```

Now in the package `@babel/types` there are no factories for jsDoc nodes also no ast node has a jsDoc field like on astexplorer.net

What is the situation with this? I'd like to construct ast nodes with JSDoc tags. Does typings+factories live in separate package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASTExplorer link has the Typescript parser enabled, not Babel's. Typescript parses JSDoc comments, because Typescript [lets you use JSDoc annotations for types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html).

Comment: I've done goofed up with this question :D, thanks!